# DHCP snooping - my clients dont get ip from dhcp

Tags: cisco, dhcp, switch, dhcp-option

Why the PCs don't get ip from Core switch Dhcp pool?
without dhcp snopping there is no problem, but when i enable dhcp snooping clients
stoping to get ip from dhcp.
This is my topology:

[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzDh9.png)

Thanks.
http://uupload.ir/files/fqsd_capture.png

Comment: Hi, an inline image is better for the reader as a separate link and you can provide both. It's just normal here, that other user can edit to improve your post.

Comment: The DHCP server is which switch? Where did you activate DHCP snooping?

Answer (score 1):

when you activate DHCP snooping you need to define one or more trusted interfaces connected to your DHCP server
i,m not sure but i think by default all ports are untrusted which means all dhcp offer or response messages will be dropped causing your PC not to receive an IP address
based on your topology you should define gig 0/1 on the switch 0 (the one on the right) as trusted port
go to interface config mode then enter "ip dhcp snooping trust" command